# Android Application - Searchable Spinner

Tags: android, listview, spinner

Hi I have a Spinner with 934 Items in it and it's too long, to make it worse it's also just become a multiple select by order of "him that must be obeyed". I was going to have it manually populate a uneditable read-only "ListView" below whenever something was picked, but that still doesn't make it search the spinner.

what I had in my minds eye was something like this

```
   ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
   +     search text           [v]+
   ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
   +   Filtered Choice 1       | |+
   +   Filtered Choice 2       | |+
   +   Filtered Choice 3       |I|+
   ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
   +   Picked Choice a   [delete] +
   +   Picked Choice b   [delete] +
   ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

if this is aiming way too high for SO I understand but I was wondering if there was any projects or tutorials covering this notion? Thanks for any help.